# No code needed at all for iad/AdMob mediation

Tags: ios, admob, iad

I signed up with iAd network. I signed up with AdMob account. I set iAd CPM higher than AdMob. I added AdMob SDK and an adapter comes with SDK. I also added iAd adapter. According to AdMob mediation publisher quick start page, after I add the SDK's, adapters and -ObjC in linker flags its states "there is no need to write additional code to create ad views from each ad network. The AdMob Mediation SDK will invoke each ad network's adapters and SDKs as necessary to create ads."

As soon as I turn on the simulator without adding any mediation code, iAd and AdMob should mediate on its own? I shouldn't include anything in viewDidLoad and bannerViewDidLoadAd and didFailToReceiveAdWithError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend this guide, very helpful for me:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/supplementing-iad-placement-with-admob--mobile-9543

Also read this:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Comment: Those are very helpful guides.